# getting an array of objects within an object - Error trying to diff '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am getting an error in my console when i am trying to get data of an object within an object and not sure what is the correct mapping to return the array of of data that i need which is `results` in this case.

here is how my json file looks:

```
{
"count": 101,
"results": //this is an array[
  object 1, 
  object 2,....
}
```

My service call:

```
 getData(){
        return this._http.get('url')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

My component file:

```
getData(){
    this.service.getData().subscribe(
      data => this.results = data,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
```

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of results">
   <td><a style="cursor: pointer">{{item.title}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access the **`results`** array inside the **`results`** object, so the **`ngFor`** will look like,

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of results.results">
   <td><a style="cursor: pointer">{{item.title}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i have tried that but i get this console error: ` Error trying to diff '[object Object]'`

Comment: did you try the above?

Comment: i wasn't sure if i have to change something in my mapping once i get the data to directly get the results object

Comment: results contains a list of objects.

Comment: change your getData as getData(): Observable<any> {

Comment: list of objects? is it different from what you have posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144001/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-bluepearl).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `async` pipe to link observables to template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of (service.getData() | async).results">
   <td><a style="cursor: pointer">{{item.title}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

I think that your error comes from the fact that `results` is `undefined` if the request has not finished yet or if it failed. Using `async` pipe will remove this issue.

If you still want to handle errors in your component, you can to it like that:

Component:

```
public getServiceData:Observable<any>{
  return this.service.getData().catch(err => this.errorMessage = <any>err);
}
```

Html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of (getServiceData() | async).results">
   <td><a style="cursor: pointer">{{item.title}}</a></td>
</tr>
```